# Android ADT 23.0.2 and Eclipse Issue

Tags: android, eclipse

After my Android ENV got spoiled since I upgraded to version 23, I downloaded the latest ADT bundle and Eclipse is behaving weird.

First on launch it shows Unknown Publisher and doesn't give me the ADT look.

**Unknown Publisher**

[image]

**Normal ADT launch screen**[image: Normal ADT launch screen]

**Here is my new ADT launch screen**[image]

My SDK Manager is almost fully updated too

[image]

And on selecting either new/old workspace this is how eclipse looks like:

[image]

I am not sure what needs to be done, has anyone faced such issue? Do I have to re-download everything again?

I am using Windows 7 64 bit machine with Java EE 7.

Comment: Check ur sdkRoot/bin Dir for proguard'' , zipalign etc. If not there you will want to revert to 22.6.3

Comment: What happens if you open the Java Perspective?

Comment: @RobertRowntree I can see proguard and zipalign in SDK\tools and SDK\build-tools

Comment: @Tim when I move to Java perspective and click on Help-About same screen appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that my ADT update went wrong somewhere, though SDK Manager was showing API 20 as downloaded under SDK\build-tools I couldn't find it.

Finally I just installed Eclipse Classic, ADT, Eclipse ADT plugin.

Even a fresh download and installation worked correctly